# Detox won't run Android tests

Tags: detox

We are having some trouble getting our Android tests to run using Detox.

We have created a complete new react native project with exactly the same dependencies and package.json structure as the Detox Jest example.

We are able to build the android packages using npm run build:android-debug and run the tests using npm run test:android-debug.

During the execution we have noticed an exec.js/KILL after which our test runner hangs and eventually times out.

```
...

...

...

detox[33690] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #15] /Users/dorota/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell "ps | grep "com.binbuddy$""

detox[33690] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=9456756b-0d52-0847-b4a7-f7e52b993ad0)

detox[33690] DEBUG: [**exec.js/KILL**] sending SIGINT to [pid = 33711]: /Users/dorota/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:57813 -e detoxSessionId 9456756b-0d52-0847-b4a7-f7e52b993ad0 -e debug ZmFsc2U= com.binbuddy.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

However when we run the Detox jest example provided we get the following behaviour, instead of the `KILL` above we get a `LOGIN` and `LOGIN_SUCCESS`:

```
...

...

...

detox[34701] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=e0029d9a-137a-90d8-09a5-2ebd70c8410f)

detox[34701] DEBUG: [**DetoxServer.js/LOGIN**] role=testee, sessionId=e0029d9a-137a-90d8-09a5-2ebd70c8410f

detox[34701] DEBUG: [**DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS**] role=testee, sessionId=e0029d9a-137a-90d8-09a5-2ebd70c8410f
```

and the test run successfully on the device.

Can you please shed some light on what might be going wrong with our setup? Is our android project configuration missing something?

Having a glance at the android projects, we have noticed some differences between them, e.g. build.gradle and gradle.properties

build.gradle has the following difference:

```
    maven {
        // All of Detox' artifacts are provided via the npm module
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android"
    }
```

and gradle.properties has the following difference:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this issue? I am hitting a similar problem.